# Calculating the Expected Value of a Probability Density Function (steps)

Tags: integration, statistics, expected-value, density-function

I have this probability density function and I need to find its expected value:
$$f(t)=be^{-bt}$$
Which was also given to be:
$$E[X]=∫_{-∞}^∞tf(t)dt$$
$$E[X]=∫_{-∞}^∞tbe^{-bt}dt$$
I also know the answer, which is:
$$E[X]=\frac{1}{b}$$
And I understand that integration by parts was used, but I don't know how, so if someone could elaborate on the steps involved that would be amazing.

Comment: What parts did you try?

Comment: Do you have any restriction for $t$?

Comment: @saulspatz i tried it where u=t, dv=be^(−bt), du=dt and v=(-b^2)/(e^bt)?

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues i only know that f(t)=0 for t<0?

Comment: @user912154 MathJax works in comments, too.  I think your problem is just the lower limit of integration.  As Rodrigo Domingues has hinted, you want $t\geq0$  (Try integrating the density function -- do you get $1$?)

Comment: let $u=t$ and $v'=be^{-bt}$ and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Before deriving you expectation you have to understand which kind of distribution you are facing

$$f_X(t)=b e^{-bt}$$

is the density of a Negative exponential distribution, with $b>0$ and $X \geq 0$ thus your integral becomes

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty} bt e^{-bt}dt=\frac{1}{b}$$

The integral is immediate if you know the definition of [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{b}\int_0^{\infty} (bt) e^{-bt}d(bt)=\frac{1}{b}\Gamma(2)=\frac{1}{b}$$